# PHP code to Track Seeds and Peers of torrent by its hash

Tags: php, hash, bittorrent

I have an torrent hash for example `3BA918BF6B648BB6BEC6AAC716F1855451016980` , Is there any API to get the size , seeds , and peer of torrent.Just these 3 info are enough .And i dont want to scrape illegal .I want something that is permenant.

I have googled and checked stackoveflow.I did not find any info to get  torrent info via **Hash**.

Comment: Do you know the tracker?

Comment: I use torcache tracker :? sorry i am total noob